# Using awk to export a mysql table to .csv

Tags: awk

I've run into an issue where I'm trying to understand awk for a class. We are supposed to take the table full of names and some other information and divide each field using "," to make it easier to export to .csv. So far what I have removes all extra characters including the initial "," tied to the first field. I'm down to 2 last issues with my script. The first is adding the "," to divide each field. I know this seems basic, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around it. The second is that occasionally $2 is followed by an extra initial standing in for a middle name. I have no idea how to incorporate another field to every other line that does not have an initial.

The table is the following:

```
 +---------------------------------+------------+------+----------+
 | Name                            | NumCourses | Year | Semester |
 +---------------------------------+------------+------+----------+
 | ABDULHADI, ASHRAF M             |          2 | 1990 |        3 |
 | ACHANTA, BALA                   |          2 | 1995 |        3 |
 | ACHANTA, BALA                   |          2 | 1996 |        3 |
 +---------------------------------+------------+------+----------+
```

My Code:

```
awk 'NR==3, N==6{gsub(","," "); gsub(/\|/, " "); gsub(/\+/," "); gsub(/\-/," "); print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6}' awktest.txt
```

Output:

```
ABDULHADI ASHRAF M 2 1990 3
ACHANTA BALA 2 1995 3
ACHANTA BALA 2 1996 3
```

P.S. It should be noted that we were instructed to rip out the headers.

Expected Output:

```
ABDULHADI,ASHRAF,M,2,1990,3
ACHANTA,BALA,N/A,,2,1995,3
ACHANTA,BALA,N/A,2,1996,3
```

Comment: Please add the expected output to your question.

Comment: Hi, I updated it and it should be closer to what it should look like now.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach to  first remove punctuation characters  is good. Keeping it, you could write:

```
awk -v OFS="," '{gsub(","," ");gsub(/\|/," ")}{$1=$1}NF==5{$2=$2",N/A"}NF>4' awktest.txt
```

Let's unwind it and understand what is happening:

```
awk -v OFS="," '       #Output field separator is set to comma
    {
    gsub(","," ")      #Substitute any comma by space
    gsub(/\|/," ")     #Substitute any pipe by space
    }
    {$1=$1}            #Force line rebuild so that OFS is used to separate fields outputed 
    NF==5{$2=$2",N/A"} #If there are only 5 fields, middle-name is missing, so append ",N/A" to 2nd field
    NF>4               #Print resulting lines that have at least 5 fields (this gets rid of headers)
' awktest.txt
```

Output:

```
ABDULHADI,ASHRAF,M,2,1990,3
ACHANTA,BALA,N/A,2,1995,3
ACHANTA,BALA,N/A,2,1996,3
```

Feel free to request further clarification if you need it.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I misread some of my instructions and this does help a lot and explains quite a bit. now I'm having an issue with the table that basically has a row count below the table and I need to remove that one now.